# How to make DtsClient use the correct version of Integration Services

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I have a .Net application (VS2017 4.6) that consumes data from SSIS packages using the method described [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-the-output-of-a-local-package?view=sql-server-2017) The packages are developed with SQL Data Tools for VS2012 (so the target is SQL Server 2012). The idea is that the program calls the package execution and waits for the return of a DataReader result to process. *This works fine on the Dev machine* (as always).

I'm trying to deploy the solution to a server machine that has SQL Server 2008, 2012 and 2014 coexisting, but it's not working, with a return error of "Package failed to load".

- I modified the software and the package to include a Logging component that gave a more verbose report. The actual error is this: **To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install *myDataReaderName* of Integration Services or higher.**
- Even though all the instances seem to have some for of DTS components (their DTS\Binn folders exist and have DTExec.exe files), according to the SQL Server 2014 installed components report, only the 2014 instance actually has Integration Services installed. I guess the other instances have the files because of the import/export components?
- I tried to execute the package with the DTExec/DTExecui utility for all instances, and in fact only the 2014 instance succesfully executed the package. The 2012 instance (same exact version as the dev machine) returns the same **To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install *myDataReaderName* of Integration Services or higher.** error.
- So, I tried to change the Path environment variable and rename all the DTExec.exe files except the 2014 version to try and force the DtsClient component to use the "correct" version, but to no avail.

So, what I'm doing wrong? I thought that SSIS packages targeted for 2012 could be run by 2014. It actually CAN be run with the 2014 instance from the DTExec utility, but not from inside my application, so it seems to me the .Net wrapper is "confused" and picking the 2012 instance. What are my options here?

Comment: You can't use VS 2010 (not 2012) with SSDT 2012 to develop packages for SQL Server 2008; you need to use Visual Studio 2008 with BIDS 2008; the set up for 2008 and 2012 is **very** different. Also, no packages created for SQL Server 2012 cannot be run on 2014; the packages need to be built as 2014 packages.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a server machine that has SQL Server 2008, 2012 and 2014 coexisting"?   Because what I think that means isn't possible.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not interested in developing for SQL 2008, but for 2012 and up. I'm using VS2012 with SQL2012, and thought that it could run in the SSIS 2014 instance. EDIT: The package DOES run in the 2014 instance, when run from the DTExec utility, it just doesn't run from inside the .Net app.

Comment: @TabAlleman you can have as many SQL Server instances as you want in the same machine, no matter the versions. What do you mean it isn't possible?

Comment: @KalaNag because SSIS servers have to be on the root instance, of which there can be only one; unless you're talking about virtual servers on the same physical box.

Comment: @TabAlleman sorry, I thought you meant SQL Server instances. There is only one SSIS instance, and it is 2014.

Comment: Well then, when you deploy an SSIS package to the server, it's going to have to be 2014.  The other SQL Server instances won't allow you to run SSIS packages in any version you want.   The version of the SSIS server is the only one that matters.